# Show/Hide div using bootstrap checkbox - require inputs to be entered only if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok,  I've been having a really weird problem using a checkbox which collapses a hidden div using bootstrap.

if I have data-toggle="collapse" in the checkbox input attribute section, the Div Collapses but requires that every single one of the inputs inside it be filled out.

If data-toggle="collapse" is not there, the hidden div doesn't collapse, and if the checkbox is checked it requires the inputs to be entered and if it's left unchecked I can submit the form without the inputs being entered.  (desired action, but the div doesn't hide or show when the checkbox is checked)

How do I hide/show the div when the checkbox is unchecked/checked AND only require the inputs if the box is checked?

I'm using this as the HTML:

```
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="checkbox" onclick="ChangeShip()" href="#moreabout" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="moreabout" class="form-control" id="chShipAdd" name="chShipAdd" value="no">
                    </div>
                    <label for="chShipAdd" class="col-md-3 control-label">Shipping Information?</label>
                        <div id="shipadddiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
                            <div class="collapse" id="moreabout" >
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <br>
                                        <input id="sStreet" name="sStreet" type="text" placeholder="Street Name (required)"  class="form-control shipClass" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="sCity" name="sCity" type="text" placeholder="City (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="sState" name="sState" type="text" placeholder="State (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">&nbsp;</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="sZipcode" name="sZipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
function ChangeShip() {
      if (!(document.getElementById('chShipAdd').checked)) {
       document.getElementById('shipadddiv').style.visibility="hidden";
       $(".shipClass").prop("disabled",true);
      }
      else {
      document.getElementById('shipadddiv').style.visibility="visible";
      $(".shipClass").prop("disabled",false);
      }
  }
```

Any solution that WORKS will be acceptable.  I've bashed my brain all day trying to do this simple action.   I've tried .prop  .attribute  .setAttribute .removeAttribute, and much much more.

Any Advice?

Comment: Can you simplify that question / code, and put the code in a snippit?  That's a big wall of text.

Comment: If I remove data-toggle="collapse" from the checkbox - the 'disabled' attribute gets set to each of the inputs in the hidden div, BUT the div doesn't collapse.

If I add the data-toggle="collapse" the hidden div shows and hides itself, but regardless of if it's shown or hidden, ALL of the inputs are required.  Also, the checkbox doesn't show as checked or unchecked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jquery to solve this quickly. You can wrap your inputs for change ship and give it and `id`. And let jquery do the rest.

```
var form = $('#myForm'),
checkbox = $('#changeShip'),
chShipBlock = $('#changeShipInputs');

chShipBlock.hide();

checkbox.on('click', function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      chShipBlock.show();
      chShipBlock.find('input').attr('required', true);
   } else {
      chShipBlock.hide();
      chShipBlock.find('input').attr('required', false);
   }
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdme/3amv9y7y/13/) for your problem. This should help you.

Comment: I checked out your jsfiddle, and it is working exactly as I intended.  I will make this change ASAP tomorrow morning and hopefully all goes well.  I thank you SO MUCH for your time.  Sorry for the confusion.  Couldn't exactly word it too well.  It's been one problem after another. ;)

Comment: You're welcome @MortHub ... I also have that problem that's why google is very useful.. :)

Answer (score 2):

your click event will toggle the display and the disabled, but when the form is loaded you will have hidden content that is not disabled.

simply call the function on document.ready

```
function ChangeShip() {
   var show = $('#chShipAdd').prop('checked');
   $('#shipadddiv').toggle(show);
   $("#shipadddiv .shipClass").prop("disabled", !show);
}

$(ChangeShip); // call on document.ready
```

or simply add the disabled attribute to those elements so that the initial form state is valid

If the [required] attribute is still triggered on a [disabled] element you could juggle the attribute value

```
function ChangeShip() {
   var show = $('#chShipAdd').prop('checked');
   $('#shipadddiv').toggle(show);
   $("#shipadddiv .shipClass").each(function(){
       if (!('_required' in this))
           this._required = this.required;

       this.disabled = !show;
       this.required = (show) ? this._required : false;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I added $(document).ready(function(){ ChangeShip(); }); and changed the ChangeShip function to how you have it and it still seems to do the same thing.  Can't submit the form without filling in the fields.  I tried with and without the data-toggle="collapse"

Comment: added updates, accounts for fields that may or may-not be set to required, but if they are all required then you can simply toggle the required prop with $("#shipaddiv .shipClass").prop("required", show);

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="ChangeShip()" href="#moreabout" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="moreabout" class="form-control" id="chShipAdd" name="chShipAdd" value="no">
</div>
<label for="chShipAdd" class="col-md-3 control-label">Shipping Information?</label>
<div id="shipadddiv" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="collapse" id="moreabout" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br>
                <input id="sStreet" name="sStreet" type="text" placeholder="Street Name (required)"  class="form-control shipClass" required>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <input id="sCity" name="sCity" type="text" placeholder="City (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                 <input id="sState" name="sState" type="text" placeholder="State (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
             </div>
             <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">&nbsp;</div>
             <div class="col-md-4">
                     <input id="sZipcode" name="sZipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip (required)" required  class="form-control shipClass">
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
$('#chShipAdd').change(function() {
    if ($('#chShipAdd').prop('checked')) {
        $('#shipadddiv').show();
    } else {
        $('#shipadddiv').hide();
    }
});
```